# Error setting up function to be compatible with interface

Tags: php, oop, interface

I'm getting a fatal error when I try to echo it out.

All I am trying to do is set the users name, and return it..

Interface:

```
    interface BasicPaymentGateway
{
    /**
     * Set the card holder's full name.
     * ---
     * @param   string  Cardholder's full name.
     * @return  object  Chainable instance of self.
     */
    public function setName(string $name): BasicPaymentGateway; }
```

and this is what my function looks like :

```
class BasicPayment implements BasicPaymentGateway
{
    public $name;

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$test = new BasicPayment();
$test->setName("Full Name");
echo $test->name;
```

Comment: what happens if you append `: BasicPaymentGateway` to your `BasicPayment` class's `setName` method

Comment: @Ersoy I get back a Parse Error unexpected {

Comment: It has to be like `public function setName(string $name): BasicPaymentGateway {$this->name = $name;}` and also if you are defining return type declarations then you need to return the instance of it. after `$this->name = $name;` you need to `return $this;`

Comment: @Ersoy okay thank you I got a new error so I'll work with it ha! :)

Comment: glad to hear that,  good luck with the next one.